# Django run systemcheck as unittest

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I was doing some refactoring and ran into the case where all my unit tests passed when running `manage.py test <app_name>`. However, when I went to run a custom admin command I got a `SystemCheckError` and running `manage.py check` raises the same error.

I'm surprised that the test framework does not run the System Check by default. What is the best way to run SystemCheck during testing? It seems like this is a common issue? Should I just write my own unittest using the [management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code)? If I do this I'll have to pick an app for it to be in - I'd prefer for the SystemCheck to always be called when running my tests.

Comment: Did you write tests for your management commands?

Comment: Yes, I ended up creating a test_check with management.call_command('check') in it.  I feel there should be a better solution than that.